# PROC REPORT within DATA in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-report

I am trying to do a simple thing - write a PROC REPORT procedure within a DATA sentence. My main idea is - if the condition in data step is true - lets execute PROC REPORT, if it is false - do not execute PROC REPORT. Any ideas? Code runs without errors for now, but I see that condition in IF statement is not applied and PROC REPORT is ececute despite the fact that condition is not fulfilled.

Thank you in Advance.

```
%let DATO    =  13062016;

PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.auto1 DATAFILE= "C:\Users\BC1554\Desktop\andel.xlsx"
DBMS=xlsx REPLACE;
SHEET="sheet1"; 
GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;


data want;
set WORK.auto1;
rownum=_n_;
run;

DATA tbl2;
SET want;
if (rownum => 1 and rownum <=6 ) then output work.tbl2  ;
RUN;

ODS NORESULTS;
ods LISTING close;
ODS RTF FILE="C:\Users\BC1554\Desktop\Statistik_andel_&DATO..rtf";
title "Statistics from monthly run of DK shares of housing companies (andelsboliger)";
 data Tbl21 ;
 set work.Tbl2; 
 where (DKANDEL='Daekning_pct_24052016' or DKANDEL='Daekning_pct_18042016') ;
 difference = dif(Andel);
 difference1 = dif(Total);
 run;
 data Tbl211 ;
set work.Tbl21; 
where (DKANDEL='Daekning_pct_18042016') ;
run;
data Tbl2111 ;
set work.Tbl211; 
where (DKANDEL='Daekning_pct_18042016') ;
if abs(difference) > 10 and abs (difference1) > 107 then ;
run; 

proc report data= work.Tbl2 spanrows;

columns DKANDEL Andel Total Ukendt  ; 
title2 "-";
title3 "We REPORT numbers on p.4-5".;
title4 "-";
title5 "The models coverage";
title6 "Run date &DATO.";
footnote1 "Assets without currency code not included";
define DKANDEL / order;
define Andel   / order;
define Total   / order;
define Ukendt  / order;
define DKANDEL/ display;
define Andel  / display;
  Compute DKANDEL;
   call define (_col_,"style","style={background=orange}");
    endcomp;
Compute Andel;
        call define (_col_,"style","style={background=red}");
endcomp;
run; title; footnote1;
ODS RTF close;
ODS LISTING;
title;
       run;
```

Comment: Not sure if understand your problem. So your if condition is `if abs(difference) > 10 and abs (difference1) > 107 then ;` and depending on the result proc report should be executed? If so, that does not work the way you wrote it, you need to do it with macro variables...

Comment: Hi, kl78,

yes, the point is to excecute PROC REPORT if condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

To conditionally execute code you need to use a macro so that you can use macro logic like `%IF` to conditionally generate the code.

But for your simple problem you can use a macro variable to modify the `RUN;` statement on your `PROC REPORT` step.  Create a macro variable and set it to the value `CANCEL` when you don't want the step to run.

```
%let cancel=CANCEL;
...
if abs(difference) > 10 and abs (difference1) > 107 then call symputx('cancel','');
...
proc report ... ;
...
run &cancel ;
```

Simple example. Produce report if anyone is aged 13.

```
%let cancel=CANCEL;
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class ;
  if age=13 then call symputx('cancel',' ');
run;
proc report data=sashelp.class ;
run &cancel;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom,

but could you just do that and comment here, because I tried and it didn't work out for now...

Comment: You need to post a small sample program with data if you want someone to test your code.  Try the example I added using SASHELP.CLASS.

Answer (score 2):

Tom's answer is a good one, and probably what I'd do.  But, an alternative that is more exactly what you suggested in the question seems also appropriate.

The way you execute a PROC REPORT in a data step (or execute any non-data-step code in a data step) is with `call execute`.  You can use `call execute` to execute a macro, or just a string of code; up to you how you want to handle it.  I would make it a macro, because that makes development much easier (you can write the macro just like regular code, and you can test it independently).

Here's a simple example that is analogous to what Tom put in his answer.

```
%macro print_report(data=);
  proc report data=&data.;
  run;
%mend print_report;


data _null_;
  set sashelp.class ;
  if age=13 then do;
    call execute('%print_report(data=sashelp.class)');
    stop;  *prevent it from donig this more than once;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Joe,

I tried to run your code and I don't see a point of this macro, it just gives me back the same table, so ...? Where is the idea of this MACRO?

Comment: @BC1554 It runs the PROC REPORT from the dataset.  As it's written it's more or less pointless, sure, but it's showing you how to do what you were trying to do.  It could become useful - for example, if you had parameters stored in a dataset that you wanted to run `proc report` multiple times based on.